# Datediff function between a date column and current date?

Tags: sql, presto

How can I correctly calculate the difference in days or years between a date column and the current date?

typically would use

```
  where date_diff('day, date_column1, date_column2) as difference
```

So what I need is if the difference between the date column and todays date is 3 days then 3 or 3 years then 3.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL SERVER, you can use the following query (replace the date with your field):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN datediff(year, '20120303', getdate()) > 1 
   THEN datediff(year, '20120303', getdate()) 
   ELSE datediff(day, '20120303', getdate()) END AS Diff
```

Using your sample:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN datediff(year, date_column, getdate()) > 1 
   THEN datediff(year, date_column, getdate()) 
   ELSE datediff(day, date_column, getdate()) END AS Diff
```

Comment: datedff(day, date_column, getdate())  as difference would not work?

Comment: I have changed the answer, now it sould be much clearer

Comment: meaning if the difference is 1 year or more return difference in years if not then days?

Comment: The question is tagged with "presto", so using Presto syntax: `date_diff('year', date_column, current_date)`, and `date_diff('day', date_column, current_date)`. See https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_diff

Comment: @Chris90, yes the number is calculated in days up to 1 year, then in number of years, as you requested.